# Поиск нужного поля JSON

Tags: java, json, okhttp

У меня есть json который приходит после запроса. Мне нужно вытащить `Id` из `responseBody`. У меня не получается почему то этого сделать. Как поправить чтобы работало?

```
{
  "extendedResponseMessages": null,
  "responseBody": {
    "data": {
      "UID": "23h12g321f-3b21b3h-43n24423",
      "type": "ACT",
      "Name": "Текст",
      "id": 111
    },
    ....тут дальше километр кода
```

код выглядит как то так. Необходимо получать строку в виде `id`

```
String rBody = response.body().string();
JSONObject jj = new JSONObject(rBody);
String res = (String) jj.get("id");
```

Comment: Какая библиотека используется для парсинга JSON?  Судя по структуре JSON возможно, следует обращаться к полю `"id"` объекта `"data"` как минимум.

Comment: использую JSONObject, JSON, OKHTTP/
и я не понимаю как именно обращаться к id

Comment: Из какого пакета `JSONObject`?  Покажите минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода.

Comment: сначала нужно обратиться к data, потому что id лежит там, а не в корне джейсона

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```
String res = (String) jj.get("resposeBody").get("data").get("id");
```

Comment: Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.